# How to set multiple logic using spring security tags and JSTL

Tags: spring-security, jstl

There is a sidebar settings icon in my view and im having this requirements regarding that. A user can have either of 'ROLE_MANAGE_SYSTEM_USER' permission or 'ROLE_MANAGE_USER_ROLE' or both of them.

1. If the user has either of permissions of 'ROLE_MANAGE_SYSTEM_USER' or 'ROLE_MANAGE_USER_ROLE' the settings icon should be displayed.
2. If the user has both permissions he has to be directed to the URL mapping ('/setting/systemUser/load')
3. If the user has only 'ROLE_MANAGE_SYSTEM_USER' permission, he has to be directed to the URL mapping ('/setting/systemUser/load')
4. If the user has only 'ROLE_MANAGE_USER_ROLE' permission, he has to be directed to the URL mapping ('/setting/systemRole/load')

In order to implement this i have structured my code as follows:

```
    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MANAGE_SYSTEM_USER', 'ROLE_MANAGE_USER_ROLE')" var="anyrole">

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${anyrole}">
                    <a href="<c:url value="/setting/systemUser/load"/>">
                        <p><i class="icon ion-settings"></i></p>Settings
                    </a>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="<c:url value="/setting/systemRole/load"/>">
                        <p><i class="icon ion-settings"></i></p>Settings
                    </a>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
      </sec:authorize>
```

I'm finding it hard to implement this logic with the existing JSTL and spring security tag library knowledge. Any support will be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working with your code? What is the result?

Comment: @dur this code works but i cant get the 4th requirement satisfied

Comment: What does that mean? Where are you redirected?

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be satisfied by taking out two variables from each statement that checks for the each permission. See the below code :

```
     <li class="${param.activeTab eq 'settings' ? 'active' : ''}">
       <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGE_SYSTEM_USER')" var="isUser"/>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGE_USER_ROLE')" var="isRole"/>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${isUser}">
                <a href="<c:url value="/setting/systemUser/load"/>">
                    <p><i class="icon ion-settings"></i></p>Settings
                </a>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${isRole}">
                <a href="<c:url value="/setting/systemRole/load"/>">
                    <p><i class="icon ion-settings"></i></p>Settings
                </a>
            </c:when>
           <c:otherwise>
          </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </li>
```